# Can't access home folder in an AWS SFTP Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, amazon-iam

After setting up an AWS SFTP server (Public, Service Managed Users), my user can't access the home folder in an AWS SFTP Server.

I've set up an AWS SFTP server, following these instructions ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/getting-started-server.html)).

I created the role + policy following these instructions ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/requirements-roles.html)).

I set up an S3 bucket with a "Home" directory that matches the username that I chose ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/getting-started-add-user.html)). I've also turned off blocking all public access.

I've setup an SFTP server, with a corresponding artifacts:

- S3 bucket + Home directory
- User
- Role + policy

But something about the role + policy I’ve setup for the SFTP user, isn’t giving the user access to its S3 bucker/folder. Ie, the IAM policy isn’t applying the expected permissions to an SFTP user’s home directory. This is the error I'm getting from sftp (**A**).

Inspecting that SFTP user also gives me the correct role, home directory and policy (**B**).

What's missing here, that will give the SFTP user to only his home directory?

**A**

```
λ sftp -i my_key_pair my-user@sftp.my.domain

Enter passphrase for key 'my_key_pair':
Connected to my-user@sftp.my.domain.
sftp>
sftp> ls
remote readdir("/s3-bucket/my-home-dir"): Permission denied
sftp>
sftp> put foobar.txt input/
Uploading foobar.txt to /s3-bucket/my-home-dir/input/
remote open("/s3-bucket/my-home-dir/input/"): Permission denied
sftp>
```

**B**

```
λ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=FOO \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BAR \
aws --region us-east-2 transfer describe-user --server-id my-server --user-name my-user
{
    "ServerId": "my-server",
    "User": {
        "UserName": "my-user",
        "Tags": [],
        "SshPublicKeys": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my-role",
        "HomeDirectory": "/s3-bucket/my-home-dir/",
        "Policy": 
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeBucket}"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "${transfer:HomeFolder}/*",
            "${transfer:HomeFolder}"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectACL",
        "s3:PutObjectACL"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}*"
    }
  ]
}
,
        "Arn": "arn:aws:transfer:us-east-2:12345687:user/my-server/my-user"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to figure out this issue. I made sure I had the correct setup on these points.

```
S3 bucket + Home directory
User
Role + policy
public + private keys
Trust policy
```

I also made sure I had two separate policies, as outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/users.html#users-policies-scope-down

- **general**, attached to the role (make sure there's no `/` prefix on the bucket name)
- **scope down**, attached to the SFTP user
- I removed the bucket restriction against making it public. I still think you need to have a role / policy to see it.